# Creating new dictionary after looping twice

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I'm trying to clean up the content of a csv file and then create a new dictionary out of it. I want the new dictionary to be globally available:

```
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("test_file3.csv"))

final_dict = {} #this should get filled with the new dictionary

for row in input_file: #cleaning the dictionary

    new_dict = {}

    for key, value in row.items():
        if key == "Start Date":
            new_dict[key] = value
        else:
            first_replace = value.replace(".", "")
            second_replace = first_replace.replace(",", ".")
            all_replaced = second_replace.replace(" €", "")
            new_dict[key] = all_replaced
```

It works inside the the first loop but I don't know how to get the dictionary under new_dict to final_dict

Ideally I want final_dict = new_dict.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a `new_dict` inside your `for` loop, just access `final_dict` inside it:

```
final_dict = {}

for row in input_file:

    for key, value in row.items():
        if key == "Start Date":
            final_dict[key] = value
        else:
            first_replace = value.replace(".", "")
            second_replace = first_replace.replace(",", ".")
            all_replaced = second_replace.replace(" €", "")
            final_dict[key] = all_replaced

 print final_dict
```

If there are multiple entries with the same `key`, only the last one will be included in `final_dict`.

Comment: @dstromberg true enough, but why build a new dictionary when you can access the one you want to fill?

Comment: I now have the problem that in final_dict I only have the last entry from the original dictionary. I believe it's because the original dictionary created with DictReader contains a dictionary for each row in the csv. How do I get all dictionaries from the original csv into one new dictionary?

Comment: I suspect it's because each line has the same keys; did you read the last sentence of my answer? Do the lines have (or could you give them) an ID number you could use as a key, e.g. `final_dict == {0: line0dict, 1:line1dict, ...}`?

Comment: sorry, I skipped that part. I actually need the same keys for multiple lines. One key for example is "Date" and multiple lines should have the same date. I would then later group the data by "Date". Any idea on how to do that?